# IDA PRO help -- automation command line flags

Tags: linux, command-line, python

I am trying to run IDA Pro (full version) remotely through a linux terminal as to automate the analysis and output process. I know there are plugins such as IDAPython and there is the use of the flags for terminals using the idal command. My question is whether or not it is possible to write a script in either IDAscript or IDApython that can:

1. Start the IDA Pro process
2. Pass it a file(s) to perform analysis on
3. Output this file into an .html format (or.txt)
4. All without any user interaction besides determining which files to send it and initializing the script.

In further detail: How can I pass IDA the file I am trying to analyse via command line flag that accompanies what I have been trying (idal -A)? Is there a flag to output the info into a .html file I am not seeing?

Comment: It is not needed to "Thanks", "Please", etc., if you are happy with the answer, simply do an accept/upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a linux terminal you would need to be in the directory where IDA Pro is installed, and use the following command line flags.

"./idal -B input-File"

There are several others that could be used instead of the ones listed above. These can be found at: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml

From a python script it would look like this:

from subprocess import call
call(["./idal", "-B", "input-File"])